Are there any ways for mages to reduce the experience costs of Attributes?
I seem to recall that after using the better body rote you could pay half of the experience cost of the attribute in order to remove the permanent paradox. Are there anything similar to that offered in the books such as three dots in mind lowering the experience cost requirement for abilities?

There is a reference in How Do You Do That? p22 (Permanent Modifications).  "In the case of increased Attributes, they cost one-half of the normal experience-point expense if they’ve been raised by permanent Life-Sphere Effects."
